# Beginners/non-physicists questions

Tags: discussion

I seem to be answering a lot of questions about basic ideas in physics. I get the impression that a lot of these come from people with no physics background who may have seen something on a TV science show and want to know a bit more.

I'm happy to answer these as I'm keen to encourage interest in physics and likewise to avoid discouraging it. But I wonder how appropriate such questions are for this <s>forum</s> site, and if we need a tag to distinguish such questions.

Comment: _for this forum_ \*twitch\* . http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23399/greenhouse-gases#comment54022_23399 ;-)

Comment: As ever, I'm always obliging :-) Why am I not allowed to use the "f" word?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/178438 . Also everyone doesn't like it :)

Answer (score 1):

Some random points that I came up with:

1) Usually TV shows proliferate misconceptions. They may not be *saying* wrong stuff, but lots of things are implied. Yes, it creates a nuisance but I feel that we should have a part in fixing it.

2) We should always encourage interest in physics.

3) [Meta-tags are bad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). So no [layman](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layman), please.

Answer to the actual question:

I think they're OK. As long as we can give good conceptual answers, they fit our site. We don't want to be shunning the lower level questions--they surprisingly turn up good stuff.

Though obvious freaky questions should still be closed. I guess it's more on a per-question basis on what we do.

Here's an example: [Relativity in Real Life](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/relativity-in-real-life)

The post isn't exactly physics-related--it's a tad on the psychology side. But its gotten some great answers! And it does provide some nifty concepts.

Comment: It is also important that the TV folks come here to fact-check, and the level of TV science has improved greatly in the last decade, due to internet fact-checking. So we are doing the TV producers a favor. I wish they would return the favor by dropping their crackpot stuff, and try to shine a better light on the great neglected scientists of the last century, rather than the superstars everyone already heard about already.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Yep, fortunately. The level of TV science still sicks, though :/

Answer (score 1):

I am wathing science programmes on Discovery and such regularly and I see that translations to local language **are often wrong**!  I tried to contact translation companies, to no avail.  I would be prepeare to check translations **for free**, but nobody cares.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but sadly true. The translations can be funny though ;-)